# MySQL joining tables with ORDER BY gives unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have this database design:

```
**users_tbl**
id
username
name

**posts_tbl**
id
url
users_id *FK REFERENCE to users table*

**posts_contents_tbl**
id
posts_id *FK REFERENCE to posts table
title
description
date
views
click
isDeleted
```

I'm using this query

```
SELECT a.name,a.username,c.*
FROM users_tbl a
LEFT JOIN posts_tbl b ON a.id = b.users_id
LEFT JOIN posts_contents_tbl c ON b.id = c.posts_id
ORDER BY c.id ASC
```

Why I try to run this query it gives me NULL results, sample output is like this
[image]

But when I try to remove the `ORDER BY c.id ASC` it gives me this output:
[image]

That's not my expected result.

My expected result would be it will display the posts_contents_tbl in Ascending order at the same time it won't show some null values. Some users in my database doesn't have posts data in the posts_tbl so they should not show too.

How would I do that one? Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

PS: I already have thousands record in my database.

Comment: You've got your join order backwards. The way it's phrased now, you should be using RIGHT joins, or swap the table specifications around.

Comment: Can you show me a code on that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you have to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` because you only want users *with posts* to show. The reason why there are `Null` values is because the records are based on table `users_tbl` and you've mentioned that some of them have *no post*. Right?

Try this:

```
SELECT  a.name, 
        a.username,
        c.*
FROM    users_tbl a 
            INNER JOIN posts_tbl b
                ON a.id = b.users_id
            INNER JOIN  posts_contents_tbl c
                ON b.id = c.posts_id
ORDER BY    c.`date` DESC
```

Comment: I've use your code but still it's not showing the latest posts contents in the posts_contents_tbl even though I added ORDER BY c.id DESC

Comment: try changing it to `ORDER BY c.date DESC`

Comment: i assume `date` hold the value when the post has been posted.

Comment: Okay, hold on, i'll changed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT a.name,a.username,c.* 
FROM users_tbl a 
     INNER JOIN posts_tbl b 
         ON a.id = b.users_id
     LEFT JOIN posts_contents_tbl c 
        ON b.id = c.posts_id 
ORDER BY IFNULL(c.id, 0) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really needs that `posts_tbl` data should not display if not available.And all data of `posts_contents_tbl` then you need a `RIGHT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` .

The Query like :-

```
SELECT a.name,a.username,c.*
FROM users_tbl a
INNER JOIN posts_tbl b ON a.id = b.users_id
RIGHT JOIN posts_contents_tbl c ON b.id = c.posts_id
ORDER BY c.id ASC;
```

Comment: how can records exist on `posts_contents_tbl` if the `user` doesn't post anything yet?